# What does it mean when an ETF has a negative turnover rate?

Tags: etf, terminology, european-union

In the fact sheet of [Vanguard FTSE All-World UCITS ETF (accumulating)](https://fund-docs.vanguard.com/FTSE_All-World_UCITS_ETF_USD_Accumulating_9679_EU_INT_EN.pdf), I see that the fund has a negative turnover rate:

[image: VWRP ETF characteristics]

The ETF has a turnover rate of -28%. How can the turnover rate be negative? What does a negative turnover rate indicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/turnover-ratio-time-rethink-pieter-kotze) might answer your question. It seems to be due to the formula used for UCITS funds:

> Back in the day, when it was still requirement, UCITS III used the following formula:
>
> Turnover = [(Purchases plus Sales) – (Cash in plus Cash out)]/Avg Net Assets
>
> The main issue with this formula was that **it produced a negative turnover ratio where the cashflows exceeded the total trades**, and that clearly makes no sense. It would also inflate the ratio when the fund performed many ‘paired’ trades (ie, buying one instrument on the back of selling another).
>
> The SEC uses a very simple formula:
>
> Turnover = Min(Purchases;Sales)/Avg Assets included in numerator